# Express.js, req.params not being called

Tags: express, routes, parameters

So i have been racking my brain for quite awhile now trying to figure this out and I'm still having issues.

So i define a route like this:

```
var home = require('./routes/home');
var app = express();

app.use('/home/:client', home);
```

And my home.js code looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('homeview', { title: 'Welcome',
                             user: username});
});

router.get('/:client', function(req, res, next) {
    var theClient = req.params.client;
    console.log(theClient)
});

module.exports = router;
```

And then when i try to go to this URL:

http://www.localhost:3000/home/client

Nothing happens. For some reason it never gets to the second router.get and never logs anything. Anyone notice whats wrong?

Comment: What happens if you change your `app.use` to: `app.use('/home', home)` and then keep your `home.js` as-is?

Answer (score 0):

Working solution @ https://github.com/rmjoia/expressRoutes

app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    homeRouter = require('./home');

app.use('/home', homeRouter);

app.route('/')
    .all(function (request, response, next) {
        // Do some plumbing stuff
        next();
    })
    .get(function (request, response, next) {
        response.send('OK GET - Hello Stack Overflow');
        next();
    });

app.listen(port, function (error) {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
    }
    else {
        console.info('Server up and running. Listening on port ' + port);
    }
})
```

home.js

```
var express = require('express');
var homeRouter = express.Router();

var router = (function (router) {

    // define the home page route
    router.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.send('home route - homepage');
    });
    // define the about route
    router.get('/:client', function (req, res) {
        res.send(req.params.client);
    });

    return homeRouter;
})(homeRouter);

module.exports = router;
```